# ¡Respeten a los usuarios!

Tags: discusión

aquí estoy, una vez más!

¡Este post va **exclusivamente** a los **creídos** de este sitio!

Ayer respondí a una pregunta, que era bastante sencilla:

[¿como imprimir una linea especifica de un documento con FGETS?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/236767/6491)

Cuando respondió [@A. Cedano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/29967/a-cedano) con una respuesta que puede ser válida y/o alternativa o no, se desveló una vez más en los comentarios, como los creídos quieren manipular a los usuarios **¡normales!**

Lo explico:

Cuando respondió [@lalo2019](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/112029/lalo2019) en el comentario:

> ...gracias pero no uso la sintaxis orientada a objetos...

...empezaron [@A. Cedano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/29967/a-cedano) y [@element](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/75901/element)
a meterle caña y intentaron a convencerle que lo que esta diciendo es malo... muy malo y que lo que nosotros te decimos es cierto y punto...

y cuando [@lalo2019](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/112029/lalo2019) dijo:

> No la uso porque me da flojera aprender una nueva sintaxis

y pa que...

Además para el colmo, le **votaron negativo a la pregunta**... (Cedano o Element, no lo se, pero apuesto lo que sea que alguien de los dos era)...

¡**Creídos**!... la pregunta era sencilla y hay mil maneras de resolverlo, así que por favor pido que respeten a los usuarios si tu código no es válido para ellos... y no empiecen a convencer al mundo (incluyendo a mí.. en serio???) qué es la mejor manera de resolverlo! Es una **opción** más y no la mejor manera!!!

---

He dejado casi un año de pasarme por SOes (si sí.. y lo he sobrevivido) pero la actitud de algunos **creídos** (incluye también un moderador) no han cambiado... quizás hasta han empeorado!

Así que, mi querida comunidad SOes... a partir de hoy me declaro (unilateral) oficialmente como moderador y defensor de los usuarios **normales**, **humildes** y **inocentes en el mundo de la programación** y desvelar a los creídos y a los irrespetuosos en los comentarios y en Meta.

Bienvenido sea el 2019!

Sin más,

Daniel Arroyo a.k.a. [@aldanux](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/6491/aldanux)

---

Dejo también como evidencia la imagen de los comentarios a la respuesta:

[image: evidencia]

Comment: Dejando de un lado que puedas o no tener razón (yo creo que no la tienes del todo), el tono general de tu post me parece un poco ofensivo. Creo que hay maneras de denunciar una actitud que consideres perjudicial para el sitio de una manera mas neutra, sin tener que recurrir a insultos. Desde el total respeto a tu opinión por mi parte.

Comment: Opino como @Pikoh, de hecho, después de leer los comentarios de la pregunta original no percibo prepotencia en los comentarios de Cedano, más bien un intento de hacerle ver al usuario que hay un método mejor para hacer lo que quiere (desde el respeto y dando acceso a recursos y ejemplos).

Comment: Tras leer detenidamente los comentarios, el único que veo tal vez un poco fuera de tono es el de element. Veo los comentarios de Cedano respetuosos e instructivos, simplemente tratando de explicar que su respuesta es una forma mas óptima de hacer lo que requiere el op (el cual, por cierto, en ningún momento parece haberse ofendido de ninguna manera). En el sitio se buscan respuesta de calidad, teniendo sobre todo en cuenta que la respuesta no es solo para el op, sino para **cualquier usuario que pueda tener el mismo problema en el futuro**. No estoy para nada de acuerdo con tu post.

Comment: El problema no esta en esa pregunta respuesta en concreto... @Pikoh... es en general como se comportan y como advierten a los usuarios que si esto esta mal ...que si esto malas prácticas...y bla bla... es que esos son que leen blogs y se creen los masters of the universe..... así que si os gusta o no este post... me la suda por los codos... lo que si sé es que mientras pueda... defenderé a los usuarios antes de los **creídos**.... hasta luego lukas!

Comment: @aldanux si el problema es para los creidos usa una respuesta que denote mas lo que acusas; si observas que algun comentario/pregunta/respuesta reportala, yo acostumbro a hacerlo y la publico en el chat si no estan de acuerdo lo entiendo, tenemos tres moderadores en el cual tratan de ser objetivo y llegar a eso de verdad es muy complejo

Comment: Si te la _suda por los codos_ la opinión de los demas, no entiendo muy bien el propósito de tu post. El tag del mismo es [tag:discusión], si no vas a aceptar las opiniones de los demas, yo lo eliminaría. Por mi parte, viendo tu actitud, no tengo nada mas que hablar :)

Comment: Se puede ver la vida misma como un objeto, **una linea especifica de un documento**, el documento es el objeto y la línea específica una propiedad. En realidad es un vector de bytes, se debe buscar el i-ésimo `0x0A`. Depende de cómo lo vea uno.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo en parte con lo que se plantea en la «pregunta», algunos usuarios son (somos) un poco intensos y pesados con las buenas prácticas y queremos promoverlas casi que a cualquier precio, pero también veo muchas emociones y descargas de energía, y noto que la posición del OP de esta pregunta es la misma de los dos usuarios a quienes cita. Lo que veo aquí no es más que una lucha de egos, algo así como «ustedes no pueden saber ni saben más que yo».

Comment: En este caso apoyo bastante a @aldanux se que mi comentario caerá mal en algunos pero yo he sido testigo de la prepotencia que maneja el señor A. Cedano con la diferencia de que yo siempre lo ignoro y no pongo ninguna "queja" hasta hoy, es demasiado creído y siempre quiere que todo el mundo solucione las cosas a la manera de él. si la solución es otra para él está mal implementado y tampoco creo que eso sea correcto, si OP quiere una solución de x forma para qué armar tanto alboroto por tratar de inculcarle otra forma? el OP decide como quiere programar.

Comment: @Pikoh - No me ha quedado otra...He tenido que poner una etiqueta por obligación... este post es una declaración... P.D. Me gusta el comentario de Shaz... lo ha clavado exactamente el asunto...

Comment: Es curioso que digas eso porque en ese comentario se dice que pecas del mismo defecto que criticas

Comment: @blonfu - el caso es que lo ha clavado... del resto ya me ocuparé yo....

Answer (score 12):

¡Bienvenido nuevo moderador!

Sin embargo, siento comentarte que ya lo eras, como lo somos todos en este sitio.

El sitio se modera por los usuarios, y hay cosas que escapan del control y del gusto de todos.

Responder a una pregunta con un método que es el correcto, aunque al usuario le de flojera, es lo qué hay que hacer.

Sin embargo, coincido con vos en que no hay que convencer a nadie que use nada en particular. Yo tuve mil discusiones respecto a los usuarios que lo primero que dicen es que tu consulta esta mal porque no le pasas parámetros como corresponde, si no que concatenas una cadena. Y cansa, decirles a ciertos usuarios experimentados, que hay que ver el contexto. Si OP no quiere usar POO porque le da flojera, que no lo use. Y punto. Ya lo tendrá que usar, o caerá en sus propias consecuencias.

Indicar posibles "errores" o "fallos" es correcto. Sin embargo, una respuesta trivial que soluciona el problema y no genera más problemas, está perfecto.

No es cuestión de defender a los usuarios, aunque muchas veces parece que necesitan que los defiendan. La comunidad sola te dará la razón si tu respuesta es mejor y soluciona el problema sobre otras respuestas, más allá de lo que diga OP.

Para colmo, si miro solamente la pregunta que marcaste, la pregunta aunque bien formulada, no parece indicar que OP haya investigado algo (en ese caso yo ni la puntúo) y tu respuesta, es vaga y no explica nada (más allá que sea correcto tu método).

Entonces también hay que tomar en cuenta todo eso. Vos tampoco le dijiste si con la función que esta usando OP (fgets) podía o no hacerlo. Y entonces, si me pongo a hilar fino, nadie respondió la pregunta, sólo le dieron alternativas, y no explicaron el por qué.

Yo personalmente prefiero contestar la pregunta del usuario, y llegado el caso, orientar por un camino mejor, si veo que la ruta que tomó no parece la ideal, sobre todo si es porque con la experiencia de cada uno, sabe que lleva a un mal camino.

Comment: No he criticado en ningún momento la calidad de las respuestas... (a mi personalmente me da igual si es solo código o tiene 100 párrafos... mientras que solucione el problema del OP)... Lo que quiero decir es que soy... digamos... sensible contra los **prepotentes**, **creídos** o como lo quieras llamarlo... Y sí...somos todos __moderadores__... pero la mayoría os concentráis de dar un mal sabor a los nuevos de la comunidad y recomendar cosas que ni siquiera tiene importancia al problema! En fin... yo me entiendo... y cortaré poco a poco a esos individuos las alitas hermosas que poseen....

Comment: En ese caso, la forma de defender al usuario seria explicarle porque lo que esta haciendo esta mal, dentro de la respuesta, y dejarle la solucion "mala" tambien. y asi el usuario no va a tener que pelearse con nadie, porque sabe que esta mal y los posibles problemas que tiene. y fin de la discucion. @aldanux

Comment: luego de leer la pregunta, y las respuestas, viene la mía en el siguiente break. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Como dice [@Gbianchi](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3924/28035) , en StackOverflow

**`TODOS SOMOS MODERADORES`**

Y lo que tu quieres decir ya existe lo puedes observar en

> [Nuestro  Codigo de Conducta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct)

Si consideras que una Pregunta/Comentario/Respuesta  **ofensivo**, puedes reportarlo , esto caera en cola de [revision](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review) , donde varios usuarios revisaran y podran aceptar o rechazar tu sugerencia.

Si crees que el contenido es mas que ofensivo/peligroso reportalo directamente y uno de nuestro moderadores actuara lo mas pronto posible
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

De igual forma , con tus palabras se podria decir que tu puedes estar violando nuestro codigo de conducta al decir

> He dejado casi un año de pasarme por SOes (si sí.. y lo he
>   sobrevivido) pero la actitud de algunos creídos (incluye también un
>   moderador) no han cambiado... quizás hasta han empeorado!

Si consideras que una o varias acciones de los moderadores seleccionados son incorrecta adelante, usa el [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=es.stackoverflow.com) Ellos son personas como tu y pueden equivocarse, su punto de vista puede ser incorrecto

---

En cuanto a la pregunta que mencionas.. para mi es de Baja Calidad con el simple hecho de [leer el manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.fgets.php) es suficiente

Answer (score -5):

Te comento lo siguiente y por lo cual SI estoy respetando al OP y a los demás en general

- Cuando se le hace la observación respecto a la implementación de una respuesta el dice que no *por que le da flojera*, a lo cual le recomiendo que no es una actitud que le va a ayudar a ser autodidacta por que estoy seguro después le costará moverse entre tecnologías
- Le dije que es una mala actitud, por que no querer aprender una nueva sintaxis lo llevara a poder encontrar una cantidad muy limitada de respuestas que lo beneficien, por eso lo considero una mala actitud, por que solo se estará limitando en cuanto a conocimiento
- Respecto a la acusación de ser creido, la rechazo por que soy el primero en calificar positivo a quien responde o pregunta con calidad
- Rechazo la señalización por que también acepto cuando un usuario me califica negativo(como me ha pasado en mas de una ocación) por que es claro y muy claro que no lo se todo
- Deberías aprender a interpretar lo que revisas, en ningún momento le trato de decir que lo que yo digo es la verdad única, lo que si le dije es que por ejemplo la POO es necesaria y útil y no solo en PHP lo cual es cierto; en ningún momento le dije que lo que usa el un estilo procedimental no sirve; pero como insisto así solo se va a limitar a no encontrar respuestas en muchos casos

Ahora estoy deacuerdo que puede interpretarse de un modo un tanto de regaño pero es eso una interpretación; dejo mi comentario no lo estoy borrando y pueden observar que ni me burlo y mucho menos lo humillo; pero si se le hace la observación que no puede evitar respuestas basado en una resistencia a usarlas sin fundamento lógico

Por cierto para que veas que yo no voté negativo al OP, no te estoy votando negativo la pregunta; no sea que digas que de los negativos que tiene tu pregunta también creas que fuí yo

Comment: Yo, como ya he comentado, creo que el tono de tu comentario está un poco por encima de lo que yo personalmente aconsejaría, principalmente la frase _eso es un indicio muy malo de tu desempeño_. Pero no lo veo motivo suficiente para un post como este. Para eso creo que existe el sistema de reportes,y podría haberse reportado como ofensivo si alguien lo consideraba asi.

Comment: entiendo y respeto tu opinión @Pikoh sin embargo decir que fui creido y que trate de convencer me parece también desproporcionado

Comment: Yo también, y por eso he votado negativamente el post y lo he comentado en la pregunta.

Comment: @Pikoh acepto las críticas que de esto se deriven y como comenté en la publicación que hice moderaré mi participación si a la comunidad le pareció agresivo para que esto no se repita

Comment: @element recuerda que estas escribiendo un comentario que perdurara por algun tiempo y gracias a nuestra lengua puede ser tomado  abiertamente, hay que tratar de evitar ese tipo de comentarios tal vez no fue la intencion pero nuestra lengua puede jugarnos una mala pasada

Comment: Hay que recordar que esto es una comunidad de programación, no de psicología. Eso de hablarle de la actitud del OP, es problema de cada quien. Yo he visto muchísimos errores de @element en la mayoría de sus respuestas (de hecho a veces me sorprende que tenga tanta reputación), al parecer por querer responder de primero siempre, pero no por eso voy a decirle que esa actitud no le va a ayudar en su vida, ni más faltaba.